# Why does this bone move things it isn't connected to?

Tags: rigging

I started learning how to rig; however, I ran into this issue where parts of my mesh are moving when I pose a bone they are not connected to. The meshes do not have any constraints, just the bone. I have no clue what is going on. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: rigging is pretty complex and since you are a beginner i would highly recommend providing a blend file so we can help you.